# Extjs how to get specify element after render in grid panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Hi I know this issue title is a little blurred.

I have a grid column and want to implement data rating.
I use `renderer` and return div but now I have no idea to get the elements.

My code is as below

```
{
    text: 'rank',
    dataIndex: 'rank',
    flex: 1,
    tdCls: 'column-rank',
    renderer: function(value) {
        return '<div class=rating>' +
                    '<div data-rating="1"></div>' +
                    '<div data-rating="2"></div>' +
                    '<div data-rating="3"></div>' +
                    '<div data-rating="4"></div>' +
                    '<div data-rating="5"></div>' +
                '</div>'
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the [`rating`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/whats_new/whats_new.html#Rating_Widget) widget.

Comment: what elements do you mean?

Comment: in this case, I want to get each data-rating

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to take a look at [rating widget](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/whats_new/whats_new.html#Rating_Widget) as CD mentioned.

If you still want to implement rating on your own I guess you have to write custom component for it, setup it with rating data from grids store and reference to a certain row in `renderer`.

If you still want to implement rating on your own using `div`s you can do something like this to select `data-rating` divs:

```
Ext.query('div[data-rating="5"]', myRowComponent.getEl());
```

Answer (score 0):

[renderer](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer) function is passed several parameters when called. 
One of them, as stated in the documentation is record. 
You can use this parameter to extract record for the current row. You can access record fields just as you access model fields record.get('fieldName'). 
Example pseudo-code:

```js
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex) {
  var fieldValue1 = record.get('fieldName1');
  return '<div class=rating>' +
            '<div data-rating="1">' + fieldValue1 + '</div>' +
            ...
          '</div>';
}
```